# MVC Dynamic Action in Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is it possible to define a route in MVC that dynamically resolves the action based on part of the route?

For example:

```
`/products/create/widget`
```

Would resolve to ProductsController.CreateWidget(Widget);

I want the route to be dynamic:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Create",
    "/products/create/{productType}",
    new { controller = "Products", action = "Create{productType}" }
);
```

I need to have multiple Create actions that take in different model types but I don't want to add a new route every time I add one. Without appending the name to the action I get an ambiguous method error. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably need to create your own custom route object derived from the [RouteBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routebase.aspx) where you can assign action based on particular part of the Url. Take a look at this [example](http://hanssens.org/post/ASPNET-MVC-Subdomain-Routing.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. Was hoping for a simpler solution. I think I will just add the routes each time. It will not be a very frequent occurrence to add new types.